# Generating Series and Recurrence Relation and Closed Form

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

We have the following recurrence relation:

$b_n=2b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}$

and initial conditions $b_0=0, b_1=2$

I use the generating series method to solve as following:

Let

$B(x)=b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+...+b_nx^n+...$

$-xB(x)=-b_0x-b_1x^2-...-b_{n-1}x^n-...$

$-x^2B(x)=-b_0x^2-b_1x^3+...-b_{n-2}x^n+...$

After cancelling terms I get

$(1-x-x^2)B(x)=b_0+(b_1-2b_0)x$

And using initial conditions and isolating $B(x)$

$B(x)={2x\over (1-x-x^2)}$

When I factorise the quadratic in the denominator I get roots:

$x_1={-1-\sqrt{5}\over 2}$ and $x_2={-1+\sqrt{5}\over 2}$

I'm having trouble completing the question using partial fractions from this point, I would appreciate if someone could help me out

I am required to use the Generating Series method

Comment: Hmm... you get the wrong generation function.  You have computed the one for $b_n = \color{red}{1} b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}$.

Comment: Many thanks to Achille comment! You can easily find, **with the same method**, the generating function $$B(x)=\frac{2 x}{\left(1-2 x-x^2\right)} $$ and proceed as I showed you.

Answer (score 1):

Shift indices to get:

$$
b_{n + 2} = 2 b_{n + 1} + b_n
$$

Define the generating function:

$$
B(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} b_n z^n
$$

Multiply the recurrence by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$ and recognize the resulting sums:

$$
\frac{B(z) - b_0 - b_1 z}{z^2}
  = 2 \frac{B(z) - b_0}{z} + B(z)
$$

As partial fractions:

$\begin{align}
B(z)
  &= \frac{2z}{1 - 2 z - z^2} \\
  &= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - (1 + \sqrt{2}) z}
       - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - (1 - \sqrt{2}) z}
\end{align}$

This is just two geometric series:

$\begin{align}
b_n
  &= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
       \left(
          (1 + \sqrt{2})^n
            - (1 - \sqrt{2})^n
       \right)
\end{align}$